# GLUquadricObj How do get the position.. Is there a class definition somwhere?

Tags: opengl, position, glu

Is there a way to get the current location of a GLUquadricObj object? I've tried things like  obj->getX() and such. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to get the current location of a GLUquadricObj object?

No. Because there *are no* GLU objects in a "scene". OpenGL is not a scene graph; there are no models in OpenGL. OpenGL *draws* things, namely points, lines and triangles. After something has been drawn the only thing that stays are the pixels in the framebuffer.

Comment: is there a way to save the current position that an object is going to be drawn to right before it's drawn after the transforms and rotates?

Comment: @segFault42: You can transform the vector `(0,0,0,1)` by the transformation set at the moment of drawing. See https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Transformation and https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Viewing_and_Transformations

Comment: @segFault42 Transform feedback is probably the closest to what you're looking for.